# document.getElementById return null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

index.html

```
<body>

     <script src="js/event_handler.js"></script> 

     <div id="some_wrapper"></div>

</body>
```

event_handler.js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    ...

    $('#some_wrapper').append (someHTMLcode);

    foo(someTagIdIntoTheNewHtmlCode);
}

//Search if the tag id exist
function foo(tag_id){
    if( document.getElementById(tag_id) == null ){
         console.log('#' + tag_id + " not found");
         return;
    }
    console.log('#' + tag_id + " found");
}
```

When i append into #some_wrapper the HTML code everything is successfully displayed, but if i want to manipulate the code, example. document.getElementById(tag) return always null.
why?

Comment: You don't need `#` when you use `document.getElementById` : `document.getElementById(tag)`... See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Comment: On a related note, if you're using jQuery, why are you doing `document.getElementById`?

Comment: On a related (more helpful) note, you can [```find```](http://api.jquery.com/find/) using the built in JQuery method to traverse the DOM.

Comment: document.getElementById takes element id as is we don't need to prefix with '#' and you can use '#' with JQuery to find by id, and mor eover you are already using Jquery so then use $('#' +tag)

Comment: with the new modify i still have the error Not Found

Comment: yes hanlet, at the moment i want to check if he recognize the tag id or not

Comment: Give us the code with a running example that fails... It is impossible to help you figure out why it is broken when half of the data is missing. It is like giving us one key when the door has two different locks.

Comment: The issue is pretty self explanatory: If `document.getElementById` returns `null`, then an element with such an ID doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById takes element id as is we don't need to prefix with '#'

try this:

```
document.getElementById(tag)
```

Answer (score -2):

this work in [fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/86xvfua3/)

```
function foo(tag){
    if( $('#' + tag).length ){
         alert('#' + tag + "  found");
         return;
    }
    alert('#' + tag + " not found");
}
```

try this

Comment: try if( $('#' + tag).length )

Comment: console.log($('#' + tag_id).length); the response is 0